# Calling functions that are updating a label in parallel to the form loading and allowing the form to continue to load

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I'm calling a couple of functions during a form load and then using the result to update a label control. if the the functions are long running it stops the form from loading... so I want to make it that the form loads a works while the two functions are called in parallel and when they return it then updates the label here is the calling code both functions return an int.

This a windows Forms app in .Net 4.0

```
private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       currentCount  = func1(tes1);
       allowedCount= func2(test2);
       labelCount.Text = "Using " + func1.ToString() + " of " + func2.ToString();
   }
```

Comment: Clarification: your question says about your functions that "when they return, it then updates the label". But I see that title talks about "functions that are updating a label in paralell." So, do you want just the values updated, which is sounds like in the body of the question? Or are you going for updating the label continuously while the functios run? Your code seems to support the latter, although now that I have looked over everything again, I see you're calling `func1.ToSTring()` and `func2.ToSTring()` which I don't think is what you want.

Comment: Also, what are `test1` and `test2`, you don't mention them so I'm wondering if those are intended to convey an idea I'm not catching.  Oh,and also, if you do want them to update continuously, what was the idea? Are the functions constanly setting currentCount/allowedCount while running? Or some other variable? Or calling a notification function? If you can clarify things a bit by editing your question, I would perhaps be able to rework the answer I gave to be more applicable to your situation.

Comment: Hi Shelley Sorry for the confusion :( Its a one time update spawned at load time. test1 and test two are strings which control what data is counted. I will see if I can edit the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### updated 2001-08-27 to add continuous updates

I updated the code to also show how to use a .Forms GUI timer component to update a status bar label as background updates occur, also with some various cleanup and additional comments.  It's certainly also possible to do an Invoke() to update your form with information as it comes in, but I think it really doesn't make much sense to do so. The goal of a UI update is to have adequate visual feedback given to the user, and there's no need to couple the updating of the fields to the updating of the visual element.

Also if these updates come in frequently enough, you could end up with a big performance hit from all the calls to Invoke unless you rate-limit them, which is basically what is happening with the timer component anyway.

I have zipped up the solution and have made it available for download: [ParallelButtons-7208779.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/file/jq6velkucswwsg7/ParallelButtons-7208779.zip). I'm not entirely certain why I chose that name, but there ya go. :)

So, the code now demonstrates how to do both:  what I had originally interpreted the question to mean (to run two threads in parallel in the background, updating a label once both functions of returned), as well as adding in periodic updates of separate counter fields in the background threads that also have a status shown on the GUI, implemented by a `Timer` component updating the labels in its `Tick` event.

For the final update based when the threads end, this setup doesn't require any synchronization beyond what the structure already provides, at least from the perspective of updating things; I don't know what your actual functions are doing. (If they interact with one another, they may have some synchronization requirements.)  It also very quickly updates the form without even having to worry any sort of coordination or synchronization between the two threads in order to figure out which is responsbile for updating the GUI.

#### Form Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ParallelButtons_7208779
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tslblRunStatus.Text = "Updating: please wait...";
            tslblFinalStatus.Text = "";

            Thread BackgroundThread =
                new Thread(() => TwoParallelCalls_UpdateOnlyOnReturn());

            BackgroundThread.Start();

            // tmrUpdateStatus is a timer component dropped onto the
            // form in design mode. it's initial settings are defaults
            // Interval=100, Enabled=false, and it's Tick event has 
            // been hooked up to tmrUpdateStatus_tick
            tmrUpdateStatus.Start();
        }

        // the nice thing about the component timer is that we don't 
        // have to worry about doing an Invoke, we already know that the
        // Tick event is happening on the UI thread.
        private void tmrUpdateStatus_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // in case a tick fires after both functions complete
            if ((currentCount == -1) || (allowedCount != 1))
            {
                tslblRunStatus.Text =
                    string.Format(
                        "[running...] Using {0} of {1}",
                        runCurrentCount, runAllowedCount
                    );
            }
            else
            {
                // We can use this to stop the timer since we are doing the
                // check in here. If we didn't need to prevent an extra
                // update after the functions were complete, we could skip
                // the check in here and stop it elsewhere. (see below)
                tmrUpdateStatus.Stop();
            }
        }

        // The nice thing about having a common method that fires both 
        // functions and then waits for both is that no special thread
        // synchronization is needed.
        //
        // Otherwise there would be a need to use some sort of 
        // sychronization method (e.g. Semaphore, Mutex, lock) to ensure 
        // that the update is handled correctly.
        private void TwoParallelCalls_UpdateOnlyOnReturn()
        {
            // initializing with Lambdas that just set the fields to the
            // result of the function calls.
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => currentCount = func1());
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => allowedCount = func2());

            // start both threads and wait for both to finish
            thread1.Start(); 
            thread2.Start();            
            thread1.Join(); 
            thread2.Join();

            // using Invoke to safely update the .Forms GUI component.
            Invoke((Action)
                (() => 
                {
                    // this stops the UI update timer from this function, 
                    // we can do this instead of checking status in the
                    // Tick event if we can tolerate extra updates.
                    tmrUpdateStatus.Stop();

                    // set the final status test to the label
                    tslblFinalStatus.Text =
                        string.Format(
                            "[final] Used {0} of {1}",
                            currentCount, allowedCount
                        );
                }
                ));
        }

        #region Background Thread Functionality

        // The following functions are just dummy methods to udpate something
        // in the background we can use to watch the results on the UI.

        // In this section, I just have two methods that run in the background
        // updating some member fields. 

        // fields for intermediate values (set internally while running)
        int runCurrentCount = -1;
        int runAllowedCount = -1;

        // fields for a final result (set externally using return value)
        int currentCount = -1;
        int allowedCount = -1;

        // holds how long we want the test threads to run
        TimeSpan TestRunTimespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

        // These methods use the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class which
        // has been around since .NET 2.0.

        // If you are really wanting to do a task that requires something
        // to happen at particular intervals, you should probably look at
        // an interval timer of some sort. There are several timers
        // available, There are various concerns when choosing one, so 
        // I highly recommend doing research (Stack Overflow has some
        // good answers on this issue if you search on 'Timer'.)
        //
        // Timers: System.Windows.Forms.Timer, System.Threading.Timer,
        // System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer, System.Timers.Timer

        private int func1()
        {
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();

            while (stopWatch.Elapsed < TestRunTimespan)
            {
                runCurrentCount += 5;
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            runCurrentCount += 10;

            return runCurrentCount;
        }

        private int func2()
        {
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();

            while (stopWatch.Elapsed < TestRunTimespan)
            {
                runAllowedCount += 10;
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            runAllowedCount += 10;

            return runAllowedCount;
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

#### Form Designer Code

```
namespace ParallelButtons_7208779
{
    partial class frmMain
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.statusStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip();
            this.tslblRunStatus = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
            this.tslblFinalStatus = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
            this.tmrUpdateStatus = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.statusStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // statusStrip1
            // 
            this.statusStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
                this.tslblRunStatus,
                this.tslblFinalStatus});
            this.statusStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 208);
            this.statusStrip1.Name = "statusStrip1";
            this.statusStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(431, 22);
            this.statusStrip1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.statusStrip1.Text = "statusStrip1";
            // 
            // tslblRunStatus
            // 
            this.tslblRunStatus.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.Border3DStyle.SunkenInner;
            this.tslblRunStatus.Name = "tslblRunStatus";
            this.tslblRunStatus.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 17);
            this.tslblRunStatus.Text = "Item {0} of {1}";
            // 
            // tslblFinalStatus
            // 
            this.tslblFinalStatus.Name = "tslblFinalStatus";
            this.tslblFinalStatus.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 17);
            this.tslblFinalStatus.Text = "final status";
            // 
            // tmrUpdateStatus
            // 
            this.tmrUpdateStatus.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.tmrUpdateStatus_Tick);
            // 
            // frmMain
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(431, 230);
            this.Controls.Add(this.statusStrip1);
            this.Name = "frmMain";
            this.Text = "Background Form Updates - Stack Overflow 7208779";
            this.statusStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.statusStrip1.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip statusStrip1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel tslblRunStatus;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel tslblFinalStatus;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmrUpdateStatus;

    }
}
```

Comment: .NET? we're not using FORTRAN?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

A more cohesive variation which doesn't update the label until both func1 and func2 are finished:

```
private void UpdateCountInBackground()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
            int current = 0, allowed = 0;

            Task.WaitAll(
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => current = func1()),
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => allowed = func2()));                   

            Invoke(new Action(() => 
                labelCount.Text = "Using " + current.ToString() + " of " + allowed.ToString()));
        });
}
```

**Original**

You can do something like this with [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx).

```
private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)         
{        
    Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(func1).ContinueWith(t => { currentCount = t.Result; UpdateLabel(); });
    Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(func2).ContinueWith(t => { allowedCount = t.Result; UpdateLabel(); });
}
```

Then you need:

```
private int currentCount, allowedCount;

private void UpdateLabel()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(UpdateLabel));
    }
    else
        labelCount.Text = "Using " + currentCount.ToString() + " of " + allowedCount.ToString();
}
```

This will execute the two long-running methods in parallel, and when each one finishes it will update the label thread-safely.

Comment: THanks when trying this I get: Error 5 'int' does not contain a definition for 'ContinueWith'

Comment: @Adrian: weird.. it compiles and runs without error for me. I can't even figure out how you could get that message. Make sure you having `using System.Threading.Tasks;` and your project targets .NET 4.0.

Comment: +1 for concise example of tasks (you know, so whenever I start using this newfangled .NET 4.0 thing you talk about, I will know how to do it.) :P

Comment: @shelley: Come on up to the new world. JOIN US! :)

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need is to create new thread and start it.

```
private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        currentCount  = func1(tes1);
        allowedCount= func2(test2);
        labelCount.Text = "Using " + func1.ToString() + " of " + func2.ToString();
    });
    thread.Start();
}
```

<strike>To my mind that's all you need to do in winforms.</strike> 
I was wrong - you will need to call invoke function.

Comment: Two problems with this: Firstly it will cause cross thread exception or just not work when updating the label, and secondly it executes the two long-running methods in series instead of parallel (I think Adrian wants them in parallel with each other, but the question is ambiguous about that; he might just want them in parallel with the form loading but not each other).

Comment: Tested - yes, you're absolutely right...
I read before Dispatcher isn't used in winforms, so I was sure it's possible to work with UI elements from any thread. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
new Thread(() => { /* make stuff and finally*/ formObject.Invoke });
```

A more detailed example of updating UI from non UI threads in WinwdowsForms can be found at Microsoft's page on [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28VS.80%29.aspx) or in this [Example](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml).

Comment: that change to the formatting ended up hosing the link formatting and now it looks really off. unless there's a new Invoke syntax. :)

Comment: I was just worried that someone unfamiliar would not be able to figure out what `frmObject.[Invoke][1]` meant since it almost looks like an array... Also your link to `Control.Invoke`'s help didn't work. I edited it so the link was outside the code block.